# java-update text in a JTextArea before the method is running

Tags: java, swing, updates, jtextarea

I have two classes, GUI and Test.

In GUI, it has a `JTextArea` and a button. When the button is click, the method `running()` in Text is called. listener of the button is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

  if (event.getSource() == start)  //start is the button
  {
       textArea.setText(" Testing starts!");
       pane.updateUI();
       new Text().running(this);
  }
}
```

And the running() in class Text as follows:

```
public void running(GUI gui) {
    gui.textArea.setText("clientIP IS:"+clientIP);
gui.pane.updateUI();
    .......
}
```

When I click the start button in GUI, the running method in class Test is performed. However, the text in the textArea is updated after method running() is finished.

How can I update the text before the method is called?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You're most likely freezing _event dispatcher thread_ (EDT) - read very important lesson about [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: No need to call updateUI() anywhere.

Comment: With just a code snippet, we won't be able to duplicate the problem. For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thanks. It is weird. Now it works without updatUI() but not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your update method in defendant thread. so try to wrap your logic with:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //update
    }
});
```

Read more about [Swing Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: THANKS @Salah. When I added defendant thread for method `running()` in the `actionPerformed()`, the "Testing starts" is updated directly. But for the text updating in the running mehthod, what should I do?

Comment: If I added thread for the `gui.textArea.setText("clientIP IS:"+clientIP)`, it will ask for clientIP to be final. But clientIP cannot be final.

Comment: Can you post more code, where do you create `clientIP` !!, i think it is a local variable ?

Comment: Now my code becomes: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() { new Test().running(this);}});` Now there is an error:The method running(GUI) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})     . How can I change the GUI argument to be Runnable type?

Comment: just add `implements Runnable` to the class declaration.